# How can print after point php

Tags: php

How can print after point two symbols something like that (92.25)

I have line like this:

```
$amount =($order['total'] * $this->currency->getvalue($order['currency_code']));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to always show two decimal places, you can use:

```
number_format(51 * 1.2, 2)
```